# Flutter: Post data in firebase even if the app is in terminated state (flutter)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, geolocation

I am trying to post data (users current location) even when the app is terminated state. I have managed to get above functionality in foreground state but for terminated state it doesn't work. I am attaching the code below of what I tried so far

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      addInDatabase(0.0,0.0);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot get the user's location when the app is turned off or when the user decline 'allow location button'.

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ the permission is allowed in settings for testing purpose, I found a package called as background_locator for that;

Comment: i never used that before but I think for testing purpose it will work but when you release the app in play store or app store it will be removed for sure.

Comment: Hey @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ thanks I was able to achieve the above functionality with background_locator_2 successor of the one you mentioned above. I wanted above functionality to track the location of medicines that we are shipping even if the app is terminated. Thanks for the answer!